# Rails: Populate collection_select using loop for days of the month

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, select, loops

I want a collection_select that has 1 - 31 in it for the days in the month.  Is there an easy way to create this loop to populate my collection_select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
collection_select :aaa, :bbb, (1..31).to_a, :to_s, :to_s
```

*Update:*

Actually, all you need is:

```
collection_select :aaa, :bbb, 1..31, :to_s, :to_s
```